# nodejs bootstrap project works local only

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Ive been trying out different things, and looking up various ways to solve it, but I'm in need of some extra hints to make this work.

I have a working NodeJS Bootstrap project with Gulp. My website functions locally.

So in my project I have the fiollowing files (among other folders) :

- gulpfile.js
- index.html
- package.json

When I locally run my project via 'gulp dev' everything seems perfect. On Heroku after deploying it gives me the error: npm ERR! missing script: start

This makes sense, because indeed my package.json doesn't have a start script. How can this work on local?

any leads?
thanks

Comment: can you post your package.json and gulpfile.js  **make sure to remove any confidential keys etc.cc** to better see what might be miss configured.

Comment: I'm using this standard project: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio.git

Comment: a crappy, he doesn't have a node file there to serve the files statically. You only need a static server for the files you are running not a node.js one. This is because the gulp is a runtime environment for development. Heroku node.js project is looking for the node.js server file and well.. since you are using gulp to host it during local development it does not have a node server. I can give you a simple file that will run your project from node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node.js file`

name it index.js

first before you start move all the current files into a new folder called **public** in the parent folder above public create the file **index.js**

once you are in the parent folder above **public** run this in the command line for the directory where you created the **index.js** file

`npm i express --save`

this will install a mini framework for node.js and save it to the project.json config

*for the index.js file this is the content*

```
/// START
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
var app = express();        
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;

// this allows the files to be visible without having to type in the
// index.html for the url simply do / and you'll get the url
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),{
  extensions: ['html']}
));

app.listen(port);
///END
```

you need to make sure that the index.js (node file) is in 1 folder above the rest of the project. The project should be in a folder called public in this case

before you upload this to the heroku get it working on your local machine

you need to run **node index.js** if you get any errors we can work through them but this is a really generic static serving node.js server.

last thing you need to do is go into the project.json file and add the following you can add it right above "title" in this case so it's easy to find later

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei! Thanks to this feedback I figured it out. I got it working now! :D

Answer (score 0):

If the code is client-side, you should serve up the bundled HTML/CSS/JS in [a static server](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/deploy-static-site-heroku). Doesn't make sense to run node just to serve up your static assets.

Comment: well, the website also has server side functionality, so it is not only static. But yes, I'm missing the server.js file... not sure why... btw, this is the basic project I'm using: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio.git

Answer (score 0):

Ive never used heroku but for my node application that is hosted in AWS i had to add a start script to my package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "set NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

You can use similar node start commands if youre not using nodemon.